# Qual è il significato di "prendersi di" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> Era come se avesse buttato alle ortiche la tonaca, la tessera del Partito, che peraltro non aveva mai avuto. Qualcuno lo aveva definito "cinico". (Anche Calvino **s'era preso del** "cinico bimbo" in un epigramma di Fortini.)

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "s'era preso di" in questo brano. Ho cercato "prendere" in parecchi dizionari ma, tra tutte le accezioni che appaiono, non so a quale corrisponda questo verbo in questo contesto. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

È contrapposta a *dare del*: Fortini aveva dato del "cinico bimbo" a Calvino. In altre parole, Calvino era stato definito cinico ("bimbo"), proprio come l'oggetto della frase precedente. Si potrebbe parafrasare con *aveva incassato l'appellativo di "cinico bimbo"*. In effetti questo suggerisce che *prendersi del lei*, a differenza di *dare del lei*, non sia un'espressione usata, e Google Ngram lo conferma visto che non trova risultati per *prendersi del lei*, o *prendere del lei*.

Da notare che, in questa accezione, il verbo *prendersi* vuole sempre una preposizione articolata, mai semplice.